# Calculate length, width and height of a product

Tags: magento

I have the following problem. I want to get the product price calculated through the lengt, width and height.

The length and width are calculated through a csv-file, but not the height. The height should be priced for each 5cm( till 10cm +0€, till 15cm +5€, till 20cm +10€ etc.).

I have tried some different things, but never reached my goal. My next idea is, that the height is calculated by two areas: the first would be a dropdown menu, where the customer can select ranges like in the example above. The second would be a text field, where the customer can write the wanted cm value. The problem is, that the customer can select e.g. "till 10cm +0€" in the dropdown and then writes e.g. 25cm. So he would get the wanted value for free.

My question: Is there a way to connect those two areas and limit the text field to the chosen dropdown range (e.g. dropdown: till 20cm +10€ -> text field limit: customer can write anything between 16 and 20cm). Or are there any better and simpler?

I thank you very much in advance for your answers.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The idea would be to use options of product.

A configuration part must be done in back office for each product where you want to set the height. In my idea there are two options : the exact height (if you need it for order) and a dropdown that will not be displayed but that contains the prices range. For this dropdown, you use a pattern like you said (till 20cm or <20 as it would not be display I would use a pattern easy to parse with JS).

On front, you hide this select and when a client enters a value for the height, you set the undisplayed select with the correct values range and retrieve the price to display to the user all in JavaScript.